How to transform Paging 3 data into tree like structure?
Hi my question is how to transform data from remote to tree structure or any structure , so how we do transormation while fetching data, because when we call collectAsLazyPagingItems() we cant do modification or such thing so how to do it properly
Thanks
This method
    val pagingData = mainViewModel.youtubeApi().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
we have to put over data directly into LAzyColumn 

so where to change to transform data.
   class RemotePagingSource constructor(private val listSection : ListSection<Video>,
     private val  youtubeClient: YoutubeClient
) : PagingSource<String, Video>() {


override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<String, Video>): String? {


    Log.i("RemoteSourceData" , "PagingSource  ${state.anchorPosition}")

   return   state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey }

                              }

val coroutineScope =  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<String>): LoadResult<String, Video> {

    return try {


        val previousKey =  if(params is LoadParams.Prepend) params.key else null
        val nextKey: String = if(params is Append) params.key else ""

        val pageSize =  params.loadSize

        val youtube = coroutineScope.async {
           // Log.i("RemotePagingSource" , "Thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            youtubeClient.youtubeApi(nextKey , pageSize)
        }.await()


        youtube.items.forEach {
            listSection.add(it) }


        Log.i("RemotePagingSource" , "Source ${youtube.nextPageToken}")

        LoadResult.Page(
            data = youtube.items ,
            prevKey = previousKey ,
            nextKey = if(youtube.nextPageToken!=null)  youtube.nextPageToken else null )

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }


}

            }

and this Pager Code as well
  @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
  fun  getYoutubePost() = Pager (
      config = PagingConfig(7  , maxSize = 200)){
      RemotePagingSource( sectionList,youtubeClient)
         }.flow


